# Riccati's Equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

While working on making problem sets for the subject, I would like to have a wide idea about the Riccati Equation. I have checked many books such as: Piskunov, Blanchard, Courant, Simmons , Arnold, Coddinton, Ross, Braun, Zill,Arfken,  etc.

From those of general calculus (Grandville) till' those books of Differential-Equations-Only, as well as few "Mathematical Methods For Physicists"-kind of books.

But I have only found it [the equation] as an exercise or a short comment about the existence of it and how to solve it: given a solution, doing the transformation and so on.

*Basically I am looking for wider theory, or even the background of the equation, more than its basic characteristics*

However, I've seen it recently in the study of Complex Differential Equations (Malmquist's theorem), as well as an application in the study of the behavior of Single Acts *[Simmons, pg. 102]* . But still, I haven't found something "deeper".

If anyone has material or a recommendation, thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how in depth you are looking for, but the following pdf goes a little bit deeper into the theory and solutions of ricatti differential equations http://www.risc.jku.at/publications/download/risc_2773/prep2.pdf I suspect you will find more information if you look for books on general nonlinear ode theory since the Ricatti differential equation is the simplest example of one.

Comment: @LilianHernández: Look at this and the references - which will provide more references from [*Equation World*](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0123.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, @JonathanDavidson,  and yep, I have checked few ones but they sometimes start with the applications , for example the predator-prey model. But I will give them change, extensively. The PDF looks good, tho.

Comment: @Moo, Thanks, I cheked that one too, but now that you mentioned HAHA I  just saw the first book (Murphy) I was like "I've checked it bf, da" and then now I realized that there's a book of REs. Funny.

Comment: @JonathanDavidson The correct spelling is *Riccati*; the word *ricatti* in Italian means *blackmail*.